# Full text search engines and security

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, devops, sphinx

We have millions of **really** sensitive documents (docx, pfd, xlsx etc) uploaded by clients into our application. In our app we have Sphinx for fulltext search in these documents. Flow is following:

1. upload via app form
2. plain text grabber from documents
3. store documents to encrypted S3 buckets
4. store grabbed plain text into MySQL DB
5. indexer from MySQL DB plaintext to Sphinx indexes stored on SSD

We have to completely rebuild the flow described above, because of security and performance issues. Plain text in MySQL database is the biggest "nono" in this solution, but we have to analyse any possible solutions on the market. Security and encryption of documents is the top priority for business. Besides this issues with Sphinx itself is on weekly basis.

Anyone who has had experience with the search engines and fulltext search in documents solutions -- I would love to hear your opinions.

Comment: There are multiple companies that develop solutions specifically made for those requirements, such as for personal health information. One such provider is Hitachi's Credeon: https://www.hitachi-solutions.com/securesearch/

Answer (score 1):

Well with sphinx specifically, there is the XMLPipe (or TSVPipe for that matter) indexer method. This is where indexer rather than reading a 'database' it executes a script and indexes the output.

So with this could have a script downloaded the encrypted data, decrypt, and pipe out the content out. Ie the decrypted data is never 'stored' directly.

Or could do something similar with native encryption in mysql
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt
The data could be encrypted in the database, and just decrypted 'on the fly' during indexing.

Also note that while the search index is not actually encrypted, its a 'Inverted Index', so while it is theoretically possible to reconstruct the words from, its only the raw words, not the full document in its original form.
If you willing to sacrifice some accuacy in results, might be able to enable say hitless indexing. Which would mean can't even reconsruct documents. know what words are in each document, but not the actual order.

Or can use a dict=crc which doesn't store the actual words, just hashed versions of words. THis makes it very hard (but not totally impossible) to reconstruct. As would need to compute rainbow tables to reconstruct documents.